# crontab run every 15 minutes between certain hours

Tags: linux, cron, schedule

Is this correct scheduled to run between 07:00 and 19:00 at every 15 minutes?

```
*/15    07-19        *     * *     /path/script
```

Answer (score 125, accepted):

Your command is fine!

To run from 7.00 until 19.45, every 15 minutes just use `*/15` as follows:

```
*/15    07-19        *     * *     /path/script
^^^^    ^^^^^
```

That is, the content `*/15` in the minutes column will do something every 15 minutes, while the second column, for hours, will do that thing on the specified range of hours.

If you want it to run until 19.00 then you have to write two lines:

```
*/15    07-18        *     * *     /path/script
0          19        *     * *     /path/script
```

You can have a full description of the command in crontab.guru: https://crontab.guru/#*/15_7-19_*_*_*

Comment: why do we need the second line? Why cant we do 07-19 in the first line?

Comment: @Gadam because then it will also run at 19.15, 19.30 and 19.45 h.

Comment: Nice answer, and special kudos, the reference to crontab.guru is worth real money.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, that's correct.

The entry in crontab would should be:

```
*/15 7-19 * * * /path/script >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: a crontab entry without `>/dev/null 2>&1` will simply send an email (local email) to root, or the owner of the crontab if it isn't roots crontab.  The email will contain the script/program output.  That may or may not be desirable.