# How to set times of jobs in crontab

Tags: cron

Please can somebody give me some advice?

I'd like to use the crontab to start a process at `7pm` and run until `7am` the next day.

I have done this, but am not sure it is correct, how would you do it?

> 0 19,07 * * * Usenamehere 
>   /home/Usenamehere/Eth/claymore/ethdcrminer64 >/tmp/script log 2>&1

Answer (score 0):

It is proposed to use the command "at" attach link: http://m.linuxjournal.com/article/1189 or link: [crontab run every 15 minutes between certain hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41743720/crontab-run-every-15-minutes-between-certain) -hours