# Cron After Every 15 Minutes

Tags: php, linux

I want to run Cron job after every 15 minutes and 4 times in an hour
like First it will run on

9:00 AM then

9:15 AM ...

9:30 AM so on.

Note: **I didn't want it like 8:53 then 9:08**

Answer (score -1):

you can use the below format to run in every 15 minutes.

```
*/15 * * * * /path/to/command
0,15,30,45 * * * * /path/to/command
```

Comment: these are two different commands ?

Comment: Yes, both are same..

Comment: # minute (m), hour (h), day of month (dom), month (mon)
first column is minute
This would do every minute in 15 hours intervals (i'm not sure even if the 2nd one would work given there are only 24 hours in a day)  
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41743720/crontab-run-every-15-minutes-between-certain-hours